# Why do I get the S3ServiceException error when loading AWS Redshift from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm getting an error when trying to load a table in Redshift from a CSV file in S3. The error is:

```
   error:  S3ServiceException:All access to this object has been disabled,Status 403,Error AllAccessDisabled,Rid FBC64D9377CF9763,ExtRid o1vSFuV8SMtYDjkgKCYZ6VhoHlpzLoBVyXaio6hdSPZ5JRlug+c9XNTchMPzNziD,CanRetry 1
  code:      8001
  context:   Listing bucket=amazonaws.com prefix=els-usage/simple.txt
  query:     1122
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:540
  process:   padbmaster [pid=6649]
```

The copy statement used is:

```
copy public.simple from 's3://amazonaws.com/mypath/simple.txt' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx' delimiter ',';
```

As this is my first attempt at using Redshift and S3, I've kept the `simple.txt` file (and its destination table) a single field record. I've run the copy in both Aginity Workbench and SQL Workbench with the same results.

I've clicked the link in the S3 file's property tab and it downloads the `simple.txt` file - so it appears the input file is accessible. Just to be sure, I've given it public access.

Unfortunately, I don't see any addition information that would be helpful in debugging this in the Redshift Loads tab.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: In which regions do you have your S3 bucket and your Redshift cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the **amazonaws.com** from the URL fixed the problem.  The resulting COPY statement is now:

```
copy public.simple from 's3://mypath/simple.txt' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx' delimiter ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the same error code if you are on an IAM role and use the IAM metadata for your aws_access_key and aws_secret_access_key.  Per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_copy-temporary-security-credentials.html), the pattern to follow in this case includes a token from the instance.  Both the IAM role's access keys and tokens can be found in the metadata here: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/{{roleName}}`.

```
copy table_name
from 's3://objectpath'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<temporary-access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<temporary-secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-token>';
```